# Can an English query be translated into a correct SQL query in more than one way?

Tags: database

I'm new to databases so I'm still learning.I just need to know are they any possible ways my text written query can be translated to a correct SQL query. Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the query it isn't possible to tell. Now, if it's simple enough, then it probably can be expressed in SQL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.